# CucumberOptions to execute feature file and Feature Folder using mvn

Tags: selenium, maven, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I am executing test using tags in the following command:-

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoketest (works fine)
```

I need to execute test using feature file and Feature folder which is not working

`mvn test -Dcucumber.features="C:/Users/xxx/xxx/feature/orders.feature"`

(not working, it does not override, i.e it picks up the tag mentioned in option tag )

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="C:/Users/xxx/xxx/feature/orders.feature"
```

(not working)

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="C:/Users/xxx/xxx/feature"(not working)
```

I need mvn execution command to run feature file and feature folder

Any help here will be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Feature files need to be provided after the tags:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoketest src/test/dev/path/to/feature"
```

EDIT:
I would use tags in the feature files to run specific features.

If you have features

```
amazon
harvest
mccoll
```

Mark each of them with corresponding tags:

```
@amazon
Feature: Amazon feature

@mccolls
Feature: McColls feature
```

and provide the path to all features:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @amazon,@mccolls src/test/resources/features"
```

The only disclaimer here is: Be careful how do you provide tags in the command line. There are options for AND, OR, NOT operations. I used Cucumber a few years ago and I don't remember exactly which was which.

I BELIEVE (but be careful) that `-t @amazon -t@mccolls` is AND operation. Run tests tagged with `@amazon` AND `@mccolls` at the same time. So, both tags required.

To run them in OR fashion you'd have to use `--tags @amazon,@mccolls`

You can try it out with simple trial and error.

Comment: Thank you for answer fenio, but what if smoketest is in multiple feature files. Actually i want to create jenkin jobs where in i need to pass feature folder name(multiple feature folders eg :- amazon, mccolls, sandpiper etc) in feature folder

Comment: I have updated image in original question, actually i want to target folder in feature file

Comment: @TanajiPadwal FYI, you can also create multiple runners and define feature files and tags in there. Then, you can run a single, or set of these runners by providing specific runner name to `maven-surefire-plugin`. I can show you how if you're interested.